# Fullsscreen background image wix

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm using the wix navigation system for ReactNative. I'm trying to create an app that has a fullscreen background image that runs behind the navbar and header bar.. with both being transparent to let the background through. However, I'm struggling to see a way to do this with WIX?

Comment: You should give some kind of image to understand what you are trying to achieve :D, also please remember there are 2 versions of react-native-navigation :D

Comment: Assuming you're using v2, this is [supported only on iOS](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/docs/styling?id=ios-specific-options) from now using `rootBackgroundImage`